# How to integrate Veracode with ReactJS apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, veracode

We have a react code which is currently running in production. Along with Sonar, we have decided to add veracode integration to our Jenkins file.

The documentation is very unclear on how we need to integrate. What I have so far is the following:

1. A new stage in Jenkins to zip the `src` folder
2. Invoke the veracodeAPI.jar with the credentials and the zipped src folder created in previous step.

This runs successfully, i.e. takes a couple of hours to run around 200kb of code and generates a score of 100. I intentionally sprinkled some `eval` statements in the code to make sure it complains about them but nothing really happened and the score is still 100. Am I doing this right?

I also tried step #1 with the `build` folder instead of using `src` and that made no difference as well. Which folder should I use and why is my score always 100?

Comment: https://help.veracode.com/reader/PgbNZUD7j8aY7iG~hQZWxQ/tO0QQBewkwZzU03rMut9Pw just check if this helps you.

Comment: Not really, our integration is fine because the scan runs as expected and generates the score, I want to know whether I need to upload the `build` folder or the `src` folder for the analysis and why `eval()` call is not being treated as a security vulnerability